# .htaccess rewrite request url starting with question mark

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I got this Joomla problem - google seems to have indexed a menu entry of mine which i had removed, but i forgot to remove the entry in the menu so now google have indexed this site:

```
http://www.madplanuge.dk/?Itemid=134
```

I wan to redirect it (.htaccess) to this url: http://www.madplanuge.dk/madplan/lav-madplan

How would you do that. i have already tried following:

> RewriteRule ^\?Itemid=134 `http://www.madplanuge.dk/madplan/lav-madplan?` [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\?Itemid=134$
>   RewriteRule ^\?Itemid=134$ `http://www.madplanuge.dk/madplan/lav-madplan?` [R=301,L]

Neither of the above solutions worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it with a RewriteRule alone because Apache will ignore the query string. Here I'm doing the redirect if the query string contains the ID we're looking for.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Itemid=134 [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/madplan/lav-madplan? [R=301,L]
```

Remember when you're testing that your browser will cache your 301 redirect, so you'll need to clear your cache to see any changes.

Comment: Yes man. Thanks a lot. That seems to fix my problem !! - I've been struggeling with google indexing my pages since i made some changes to the url structure right after i got my pages indexed and i didnt knew that my pages where allready indexed so i didnt set up 301 redirects. So now im just about to have all the old pages redirected

Answer (score 1):

You're doing 2 things wrong:

- The `%{REQUEST_URI}` always begins with a slash, so the RewriteCond needs `^/\?` instead of `^\?`
- Change the `^\?Itemid=134$` in the RewriteRule to `^.*$`. The RewriteRule takes the entire URL as the first argument, not just the Request URI.

More information on Apache rewrites can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: It still doesnt work. i corrected your 2 errors and i still cant get it to work - now it looks like: 

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\?itemid=134$`

`RewriteRule ^.*$ madplanuge.dk/madplan/lav-madplan? [R=301,L]`

Comment: `madplanuge.dk/madplan/lav-madplan?` should be `http://madplanuge.dk/madplan/lav-madplan?` because it needs to start with `http://`